# remove p2 install/update preference in menu tools

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

I must remove the install/update preference in the menu Tools' preferences. How can I do?
Thank to everybody.

Comment: Are we talking an RCP application (your tag) or an Eclipse IDE application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void postStartup() {
  PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager( );
  pm.remove("org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.ProvisioningPreferencePage"); 
  pm.remove("org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.preferences.MainPreferencePage");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about an RCP app, open your ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor class and use something like this:

```
PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager();
for (IPreferenceNode node : pm.getRootSubNodes()) {
    if (node.getId().equals("org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.ProvisioningPreferencePage")) {
        pm.remove(node); 
    }
}
```